# Can an administrator see screen time when I use my computer?

Tags: screen-capture

I'm not sure if an administrator can see my screen while I use my computer, can someone provide an answer with an explanation of how they can do it? I have an administrator on my computer, but not school level security where they have things installed.

Comment: This question is missing essential context: what kind of access has the unknown administrator to your unknown system in your unknown environment? If this is a environment where monitoring software is installed (like in some companies or schools) the administrator might have sufficient access to your system which also includes seeing what's currently on your screen.

Comment: If they administer your computer, they can install what they see fit on this computer. So technically, yes. But they might be moral issue, corporate policy, or law that might prevent them from doing so.

Comment: It also doesn't even matter what kind of software may be installed if you happen to sit down at a computer that is right in front of a security camera...

Answer (score 1):

An administrator can install whatever software they want on the computer. This could include screen recording software (or keyloggers, mouse movement trackers, audio recordings, camera recordings, programs that make copies of your files, software that inserts typos, and so on). There is really no limit as to what they can do regarding installing software, with or without your knowledge.

But whether or not they have *actually* installed such software is between you and the administrator.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is true and 99% chance that your administrator has installed some software which can have access to your screen. I remember once i used to work for a company and they used to control there users screen. They watches what they do. But again it depends on the policy of the company and entirely on the admin of the company.

Comment: "99% chance" -- this is completely overstating the likelihood. It is *possible*, but then this answer becomes no different from the earlier answer.